# Email send more than once in sendy

Tags: email, amazon-ses, sendy

issue is i am facing problem while sending email to subscriber sendy send more than 16 emails to a single subscriber.

while i am using amazon ses.

Regard's
MUHAMMAD Arslan Zia

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have right settings of cronjob the timing is "every 5 mins" like so   '*/5 * * * * php /path/to/scheduled.php > /dev/null 2>&1' I had same problem. It's works for me.